# How to redirect to different domain in Slim framework of PHP?

Tags: php, redirect, slim

Using Slim we can use routes like:

```
$app->get('/path', function() {
    include 'content.php';
});
```

We can also redirect to any other path of same domain like:

```
$app->get('/path2', function () use ($app) {
    $app->redirect('/redirect-here');
});
```

But I want to **redirect to some different domain** and none of below is working:

```
$app->get('/feeds', function(){
    $app->redirect('http://feeds.example.com/feed');
});
```

This shows blank page:

```
$app->get('/feeds', function() {
    header("Location: http://feeds.example.com/feed");
});
```

Comment: You got anything in error log ?

Comment: I don't know about slim framework. But why not you redirect to internal page i.e., some controller, then in the view you redirect to that external domain using `header("Location : http//yourfeeds.com/feed)` ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**In Slim 3**, you should use the `withRedirect` method on the `Response` object:

```
$app->get('/feeds', function ($request, $response, $args) {
    return $response->withRedirect('http://feeds.example.com/feed', 301);
});
```

**For Slim 2 only**, you can do:

```
$app->get('/feeds', function() use ($app) {
    $app->redirect('http://feeds.example.com/feed');
});
```

Comment: Exactly `use ($app)` was needed.